# For any $n \in \Bbb N$, for any representation $\phi:SL_2(\Bbb R) \to U(n)$ we must have $\phi \begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 \\ -1 &0 \end{pmatrix}= I_{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, group-homomorphism, locally-compact-groups

Actually this is a continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3719620/proving-sl-2-bbb-r-has-no-finite-dimensional-non-trivial-unitary-representa), but am asking it separately as it deserves separate discussion as an independent problem. Thanks to comments by  Exodd and an answer by Tsemo Aristide, we could solve upto step(2) and the only thing left to be proven was :

> Let $A(t)=\begin{pmatrix}1 &t\\0 &1\end{pmatrix}, \forall t \in \Bbb R$ . Then show that the normal subgroup of $G=SL_2(\Bbb R)$, generated by $\{A(t):t \in \Bbb R\}$ is the whole group.

As I mentioned in the previous discussion, I found out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922540/generator-of-sl2-r), which implies that all I need to show  that the normal subgroup of $G$ generated by $\{A(t):t \in \Bbb R\}$ contains $\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 \\ -1 &0 \end{pmatrix}$, which I was unable to prove!

NOW I THINK THAT THIS CLAIM IS ACTUALLY FALSE!

Since, for any $\begin{pmatrix} a &b \\ c &d\end{pmatrix} \in G$ we have , $\begin{pmatrix} a &b \\ c &d\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 \\ -1 &0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} d &-b \\ -c &a\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -bd-ac &b^2+a^2 \\ -d^2-c^2 &bd+ac\end{pmatrix}$ .

Now if the claim in step(3) has to be true, then for certain $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R$ with $ad-bc=1$ one must have that $\begin{pmatrix} -bd-ac &b^2+a^2 \\ -d^2-c^2 &bd+ac\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &t \\ 0 &1\end{pmatrix}$ . But then $d^2+c^2=0 \implies d=c=0 \implies 1= -bd-ac=0$ , A contradiction!

So rather it's enough to just show that

> For any $n \in \Bbb N$, for any representation $\phi:SL_2(\Bbb R) \to U(n)$ we must have $\phi \begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 \\ -1 &0 \end{pmatrix}= I_{n}$

Note that $\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 \\ -1 &0 \end{pmatrix}^4=I_2$, then since $\phi$ is a group homomorphism $\phi \begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 \\ -1 &0 \end{pmatrix}$ is a Unitary matrix of order $1 \text{ or }2 \text{ or } 4$ .

Now that's all I could come up with, unable to see how to proceed from here. Thanks in advance for help!

Just a short comment: There are statements like "An irreducible finite-dimensional representation of a noncompact simple Lie group of dimension greater than 1 is never unitary" which would give the result immediately. Please don't use them, as I don't have them at my disposal!

Comment: The claim is not false. The group ${\rm PSL}_2(K)$ is simple for any field $K$ with $|K| > 3$, so in particular ${\rm PSL}_2({\mathbb R})$ is simple. So the only normal subgroups of ${\rm SL}_2({\mathbb R})$ are the trivial group, the whole group, and its centre $\{ \pm I_2 \}$. So the normal subgroup generated by $A(t)$ is the whole group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Okay, thanks a lot. Didn't know that piece of information! Kindly write that as an answer, I want to close this question by accepting your answer.

Comment: Brozovic:  The issue with your argument is that the normal closure of a subgroup isn't just all matrices of the form $g\begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}g^{-1}$, but it also consists of products and inverses of those, and then conjugate of *those* and then products and inverses of *those*, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is the fastest way, but

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1\\
0& 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1 \\
-1&0 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0\\
-1&1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
-1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1\\
0& 1 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1\\
-1&0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1\\
-1&0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0\\
-1& 1 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0& 1\\
-1&0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: An Algebraist at heart!